# Store ID of record created by subform in main form / table

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

[image: Relationships]

[image: Form]

The table measures contains many foreign ids linked to tables containing multiple questions. The form will contain many subforms for each linked table, I'm currently only showing the linked table 'nbas_test' for clarity.

When information is entered in the subform a new record is created, how do I store the ID of the new record generated by the subform in the main table.

i.e in this case how do I store the nbas_test.nbas_ID in measures.nbas_ID.

Currently I can do this by including participant_id and timepoint _id in NBAS_test and including another combo box on the form to select the appropriate NBAS record and binding the nbas_ID but this seems a bit clumsy and unless I force my end users to do this they will likely forget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the After Insert or After Update* event of the subform, depending on your requirements, to update a bound control on the parent form.

```
 Me.Parent.txtSubID = Me.txtnbas_ID
```

---

`*` The After Update event also runs after a record is inserted, so you will not need both events.

Answer (score 0):

Link up both fields!

On the subform -> Properties (F4) -> "Data" Tab -> "Link Child Fields" & "Link Master Fields"

Comment: No this doesn't work because the record that you would link isn't created until you enter data in subform. The accepted answer is correct.